# How to integrate my Pullagable Liquidity Provider to 0x network?

Tags: 0x

I am thinking of building a Pullagable Liquidity Provider.

How can I supply that liquidity to the 0x network?
Do I need permission to integrate it so that the official 0x API can sample my PLP's data?
Do I have to create signed 0x orders and POST it to the 0x API?

Answer (score 0):

Currently integration into routing logic requires manual intervention. Your contract will have to implement the [`LiquidityProvider`](https://protocol.0x.org/en/latest/advanced/plp.html) interface. When that's ready, you can reach out to a teammate on Discord and we'll fold you in.